# Get HTML Table ID in C# function?

Tags: c#, html

In HTML page I've table with ID = "week1" and in C# function I'm using this as

```
week1.Rows.Add(TableCell);
```

I want to cast string in table ID. Suppose I've string

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
  String abc = "week" + i;
   /*
     How to do cast this string in table ID
     like above to add rows and cell in table but above is hardcoded and I want
     to make this dynamic.
   */
}
```

How to cast above string in HTML Table ID ?????

Comment: Can you explain your problem clearer please, I am not sure what error you are receiving if any.

Comment: your table should have attribute `runat="server"` then you can manipulate your table from the codebehind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your tables reside in a panel you can look them up like this. Please note that ofc you will need runat=server for them. I assume you use HtmlTable in your form ()

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            var table = (HtmlTable)pnlTables.FindControl("week" + i);

            if (table != null)
            {
                //do stuff with your table
            }
        }
```

Comment: My HTML tables are in simple web page and I want to access their ID's programatically  so that I can use in my function and add some rows and columns into that specific table.

Comment: @Yeronimo... Is the above function will work for my tables ??? or what is pnlTables in above example ??

Comment: I mean like this in your aspx. Put all your tables in a panel: `<asp:Panel id="pnlTables" runat="server>all your table stuff here</asp:Panel>`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your table in your .aspx has `runat="server"` (`<table id="week1" runat="server">`), then, in your code behind, you can simply do

```
week1.ID
```

or `week1.ClientID` (for the full ID in your DOM) - whichever one you're wanting.

Answer (score 0):

Your table should have runat="server" attribute.Only then u can access it from code behind.